# Proper way to Encode and Send String as a PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm having an issue sending a string to Parse. Here's the line where the code stops:

[image]

[image]

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var friends: Array<AnyObject>?
var recipients: NSMutableArray?
var message: String!
var sendMessage:String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sendMessage = message
    friends = []
    recipients = []

    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "edit")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton


    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView?.delegate = self
    tableView?.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(tableView!)

    let sendButton = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Send", style: .Done, target: self, action: "sendPressed")]
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 48)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.setItems(sendButton, animated: true)
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)


}

func sendPressed () {

    sendMessagetoParse()
}

func sendMessagetoParse(){

    let messageString = message
    let data = messageString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)! as NSData
    // NSConcreteMutableData
    let file = PFFile(name:message, data:data)

    file.saveInBackground()

    let sentMessage = PFObject(className:"Messages")
    sentMessage["messages"] = file
    sentMessage["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    sentMessage.setObject(self.recipients!, forKey: "recipientIds")
    sentMessage.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "senderId")
    sentMessage.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "senderName")

    sentMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            println("Message sent!")
```

I want to send the string object to my parse account. I've also used the method Parse provides,, i.e. dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) but that is also returning the same error. Any clue on the proper format or how I need to fix the code?

EDIT:

Okay, I'm no longer getting the error, but my only issue is that once I press 'send', it doesn't do anything. Here's my edited code:

func sendMessagetoParse(){
        let messageString = message

```
        if messageString != nil
    {


        let data = messageString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)! as NSData
        // NSConcreteMutableData
        let file = PFFile(name:message, data:data)

        file.saveInBackground()


        let sentMessage = PFObject(className:"Messages")
        sentMessage["messages"] = file
        sentMessage["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
        sentMessage.setObject(self.recipients!, forKey: "recipientIds")
        sentMessage.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "senderId")
        sentMessage.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "senderName")

        sentMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                println("Message sent!")

                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome!", message: "Message was Sent", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil));

                //show it
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


    } else {
        println("error")
    }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's code from the previous view controller, called ConfirmViewController, in which I tried to use a segue to pass a text label into the messageString into the current view controller, which is called FriendsViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender:     
AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "addFriends") {
        var mvc = segue!.destinationViewController as!     
FriendsViewController;

        mvc.sendMessage = messageView.text

    }
}
```

With the segue set up in the `ConfirmViewController` I then set sendMessage equal to message in the `viewDidLoad`, as shown in my first edit.

Comment: Could it be that the message is nil

Comment: I'm using a delegate to transfer a uilabel from another view controller as a string - do I need to pass the value into another label instead?

Comment: Is `error` printed when you pressed  the send button?

Comment: That's right, error isn't being printed.

Comment: Your `message` is nil check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your

```
let messageString
```

value. This runtime error you've got is probably a result of implicitly unwrapping optional value that is nil. You would want to execute your code inside an if statement like:

```
if let messageString != nil
{
   ////put your saving code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Technically the error is gone, but I'm still having an issue uploading the project to Parse. Can you tell me if there's an issue with how I reformatted the code in the edit?

Comment: You don't get an error, because your code is not going inside if statement. Probably you forgot to set appropriate value to your message variable.
Show us the code where you assign value to message variable

Comment: seems like either messageView or text value is nil. What's the type of messageView?

Comment: UILabel. The delegate transfers the information from a UITextfield to messageView, which is a label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // sendMessage = message
    message = sendMessage
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately. I'm trying to pass a UILabel (messageView) into a string (message) and submit the string to Parse. Does Parse not accept strings in the manner I'm trying to submit it (into a class in my Parse dashboard?). I fixed the code and it's now returning "error".

Comment: The `messageString` is nil or not?

Comment: Check the `messageView.text` in the `prepareForSegue` of the `ConfirmViewController`